# Adding namespace to XML document without http:

Tags: java, xsd, xom

I need to add the following namespaces to my XSD document:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="catalog.enterprise.level3.com" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

When I try to add the target namespace, it complains of a MalformedURIException, which I assume is because there is no http:// in the namespace URI. I am using **XOM** for this.

```
Element rootWriter; 
rootWriter.addNamespaceDeclaration("tns","catalog.enterprise.level3.com");
```

Could someone please suggest to me, how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace [MUST](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) be an [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) - for example:

```
uri:catalog.enterprise.level3.com
```

would work. If, as I assume, you have to read a wrongly encoded xml, your only solution I am afraid is to pick a "lower quality" xml parser which does not perform that kind of check - or complain with the person who gave you the file!